# Ansible Role design

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

just a short question which came to my mind in the last days: 
When you write roles lets say for a specific object type (AWS EC2 instance), do you write single roles for each operation like VM-Create, VM-Destroy, VM-Reboot .... or do you pack them into one role and toggle the behaviour with some kind of "action" variable.
To have all actions for a specific domain or objecttype inside one role would have the benefit that you can share role variables, defaults and subtasks inside the different actions. Also all code related to this objecttype could be stored in on single repository.
Does anybody use it that way and may discovered some disadvantages?

BR

Edit:

At first thanks for your quick answer.

To make it a little bit more specific:
We currently working on the automation of a cluster setup on different hosts which includes tasks like collecting all information from master and slave nodes to build some kind of global hash (information can not be handovered via host or groupvars now).
Other parts would be boot-strapping all hosts depending on their role (master or slave, master has slightly different tasks than slave).
On the last part we have to finalize the setup with some commands on the master node which have to be run after the boot-strap part.

The question for me is now if i should split the collection, boot-strap and finalize part into seperate roles or include them in one and trigger the needed action via a variable.

Each role for itself would not make real sense because its useless without the other. If keep it in one role (and in one repository) i could make sure that it is not driffting apart.

Answer (score 1):

I would say work down from the functionality of your tech stack to the design of the ansible role. That means, first, identify the actions and operations which you would want to execute on broad level. Say, for example, provisioning the environment, destroying the old environment, installing the packages, restarting some services etc.

Now, since we have identified the broad level actions, we can drill them down into actionable objects. My preference would be design these actionable objects as role. Keep in mind that some of these objects can be common/reused across the above mentioned broad level operations.

Since the actionable objects are designed as roles, broad level operations can be designed into playbooks, which in turn will call these roles. Based on this, we can think of where to put the variables.

Coming to repository, it totally depends on how you call these playbooks and roles. Having a dedicated repository for each role and a common repository for all playbooks make easier to update and review the code and roll-out changes. However, you have to do additional packaging to assemble the required roles and playbook before execution.